# Change file owner group under Linux with java.nio.Files

Tags: java, linux, file, permissions

I have a Linux server and I'm running an image resize job in Java for multiple websites on my server. The website files are owned by different OS users/groups. Newly created thumbnails/previews are owned by the user running the resize job. Now I was googleing around how to change the file owner of newly created previews/thumbnails in my resize program and came across this:

```
java.nio.file.Files.setOwner(Path path, UserPrincipal owner);
```

This would really solve my problem if it was Windows, but since a Linux file has a user and a group as owner I'm a bit in trouble. Unfortunately given method seems to only change the user ownership of the file. The group ownership remains with the group of the user running my Java resize job.

The websites are owned by different groups, so adding my resize job user to one group is no option. I also want to avoid system calls with `ProcessBuilder` and execute a `chown` on my files.

I do need to point out that the created files (preview/thumbnail) can be accessed via the website and it is not mission critical to change the group ownership, but I wanted it to be as clean as possible.

**Any suggestions how I can change the group ownership of a file in Linux only using Java?**

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Thanks Jim Garrison for pointing me in the correct direction. Here the code, which finally solved the problem for me.

**Retrieve the group owner of a file**

```
File originalFile = new File("original.jpg"); // just as an example
GroupPrincipal group = Files.readAttributes(originalFile.toPath(), PosixFileAttributes.class, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS).group();
```

**Set the group owner of a file**

```
File targetFile = new File("target.jpg");
Files.getFileAttributeView(targetFile.toPath(), PosixFileAttributeView.class, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS).setGroup(group);
```

Comment: If you don't have a file to use for the look up you can get the group by name with this: UserPrincipalLookupService.lookupPrincipalByGroupName(java.lang.String)

Comment: To expand on Paul's comment, you need the following: UserPrincipalLookupService lookupService = FileSystems.getDefault().getUserPrincipalLookupService(); Then, GroupPrincipal targetGroupPrincipal = lookupService.lookupPrincipalByGroupName(targetGroupName);

Answer (score 18):

I missed a complete solution, here it comes (combination of other answers and comments):

```java
Path p = Paths.get("your file's Path");
String group = "GROUP_NAME";
UserPrincipalLookupService lookupService = FileSystems.getDefault()
                .getUserPrincipalLookupService();
GroupPrincipal group = lookupService.lookupPrincipalByGroupName(group);
Files.getFileAttributeView(p, PosixFileAttributeView.class,
                LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS).setGroup(group);
```

Be aware that only the owner of a file can change its group and only to a group he is a member of...

Comment: Alternative to the last statement: [`Files.setAttribute(p, "posix:group", group, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#setAttribute-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-java.nio.file.LinkOption...-)

Comment: You might want to specify that your example is pseudo code or change `String group = "GROUP_NAME"` to `final String GROUP = "GROUP_NAME"`, since there is a conflict with `GroupPrincipal group`. At first glance I thought `GroupPrincipal group` was referencing itself during instantiation, via `lookupService.lookupPrincipalByGroupName(group)`.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the package `java.nio.file.attributes` and class`PosixFilePermissions`. This is where you can manipulate group permissions.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of this response is to elevate [one of the comments received in response to the original posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241967/change-file-owner-group-under-linux-with-java-nio-files#comment70661413_21837181) to a full response level, so that it is more prominently displayed.

Here is what worked for us:

```
//  newUser and newGroup are strings. 

UserPrincipalLookupService lookupService = FileSystems.getDefault().getUserPrincipalLookupService();
UserPrincipal userPrincipal = lookupService.lookupPrincipalByName(newUser);
GroupPrincipal groupPrincipal = lookupService.lookupPrincipalByGroupName(newgroup);

Files.setAttribute(filePath, "posix:owner", userPrincipal, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
Files.setAttribute(filePath, "posix:group", groupPrincipal, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
```

**Additionally we had to run the Java program as a superuser.**