# Java Creating files and directories with a certain owner (user/group)

Tags: java, linux, filesystems

Is possible in Java to manage creating files / directories (if program runs as ROOT) with different user/group ?

Comment: something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241967/change-file-owner-group-under-linux-with-java-nio-files

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve JDK 7 (Java NIO)

Use setOwner() method....

```
public static Path setOwner(Path path,
                            UserPrincipal owner)
                     throws IOException
```

**Usage Example:**  Suppose we want to make "joe" the owner of a file:

```
 Path path = ...
 UserPrincipalLookupService lookupService =
     provider(path).getUserPrincipalLookupService();
 UserPrincipal joe = lookupService.lookupPrincipalByName("joe");
 Files.setOwner(path, joe);
```

Get more information about same from below url

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

**Example : Set Owner**

```
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.FileOwnerAttributeView;
import java.nio.file.attribute.UserPrincipal;
import java.nio.file.attribute.UserPrincipalLookupService;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Path path = Paths.get("C:/home/docs/users.txt");
    FileOwnerAttributeView view = Files.getFileAttributeView(path,
        FileOwnerAttributeView.class);
    UserPrincipalLookupService lookupService = FileSystems.getDefault()
        .getUserPrincipalLookupService();
    UserPrincipal userPrincipal = lookupService.lookupPrincipalByName("mary");

    Files.setOwner(path, userPrincipal);
    System.out.println("Owner: " + view.getOwner().getName());

  }
}
```

**Example : GetOwner**

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.FileOwnerAttributeView;
import java.nio.file.attribute.UserPrincipal;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Path path = Paths.get("C:/home/docs/users.txt");
    FileOwnerAttributeView view = Files.getFileAttributeView(path,
        FileOwnerAttributeView.class);
    UserPrincipal userPrincipal = view.getOwner();
    System.out.println(userPrincipal.getName());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this in JDK 7 using new IO API ([Java NIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#setOwner(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.UserPrincipal)))

There are getOwner()/setOwner() methods available to manage ownership of files, and to manage groups you can use [PosixFileAttributeView.setGroup()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/PosixFileAttributeView.html#setGroup%28java.nio.file.attribute.GroupPrincipal%29)

The following code snippet shows how to set the file owner by using the setOwner method:

```
Path file = ...;
UserPrincipal owner = file.GetFileSystem().getUserPrincipalLookupService()
        .lookupPrincipalByName("sally");
Files.setOwner(file, owner);
```

There is no special-purpose method in the Files class for setting a group owner. However, a safe way to do so directly is through the POSIX file attribute view, as follows:

```
Path file = ...;
GroupPrincipal group =
    file.getFileSystem().getUserPrincipalLookupService()
        .lookupPrincipalByGroupName("green");
Files.getFileAttributeView(file, PosixFileAttributeView.class)
     .setGroup(group);
```