# Java / How to create a file with other user id?

Tags: java, file, identity

In the java program I'm woking on, I have to create files in a certain directory. My program runs under Windows with a certain user id. This user does not have permission to create files in the needed directory.

I know what user does have the permission to create files in the needed directory. How can I create files so that the file system "thinks" that some other user is doing that?

I've read the thread about [How it's possible to change the file owner in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241967/change-file-owner-group-under-linux-with-java-nio-files), but my case is a little bit different since I have to *create* the file with some other user than the one my program is executed with (in the linked SO thread the owner of an *already existing* file must be changed).

Any hints will be much appreciated.

Comment: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-run-as-different-user-in-windows-7 Alternatively one can also create a Windows service in java and communicate with that service.

Comment: You might find a Windows-centric language a better choice if you need to do things like this. Also talk to a sysop to have the windows machine fixed

Comment: As of now I think to check two solutions. One is to execute a powershell script from the java program. The script would create the file wit other credentials (there are commands for that in powershell). The other approach would be to use FTP or a similar protocol to change the identity.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is open a separate command/shell process on your host Operating System (OS) from within your Java application (e.g. using [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)) with the credentials of the other user.
Then use the host OS shell commands in this process to create the files.

Exact syntax will depend on the host OS.