# Permission issue to file written to shared drive (NAS) using Java filewriter

Tags: java, linux

I have a shared drive (NAS) attached to my Linux server wherein I am able to create and write to file usiing the following Java code.

```
String filePath = remotePath + fileName;

BufferedWriter fileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filePath));

fileWriter.write(fileContents);
fileWriter.close();

File file = new File(filePath);

file.setExecutable(true);
file.setWritable(true);
file.setReadable(true);
```

I have tried to log the permission attribute too using canExecute(), canWrite(), canRead() and all the output are logged as true.
But this newly created file is not inheriting the folder permissions. When user try to access(Read/Delete) files using Linux script it gives permission denied.

The user running the script is the folder owner while the file shows owner as root. Due to policy, the user doesn't have sudo rights. How can I make it accessible?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand this right, then your Java process is running as `root`. The created file is owned by the user that runs the process. Which is in your case `root`.

I see two options for you:

1. Let the Java process that creates the file run as the user that owns the directory. So the files will be owned and accessible by the user.
2. If the Java process must run as `root` then you need to change the owner of the file after it had been written. see [Change file owner group under Linux with java.nio.Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241967/change-file-owner-group-under-linux-with-java-nio-files) on how this can be done.